# Persisting complex XML in real time using web service

Tags: web-services, esb, etl

I am developing a web service that needs to take incoming complex xml payload and persist into relational database. The database has around 10+ tables to represent this payload. These tables have 1-1 and 1-many relationship. The web service needs to respond back with success or failure message in real time upon data load. If the data fails to load, we need to roll back the transaction.

IN addition, We need to use configuration based tool for implementation as oppose to coding it in Java or .net. We have looked at Informatica power center and IDS but doesn't seem to offer real time component to it.

Is there a ESB/ETL tool/platform that I can use to implement such data service easily?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can use SAS Dataflux to develop this process,then implement this job/process as Real-Time Services , then you can consume this Services using SOAP request , it's better within the job you do error handling and control rollback/commit.